# view history of object

Tags: opportunity-history

say I have a Salesforce object like an Opportunity or an Account. Is there any way to view the history of that object (what changes have been made and by who)? I am an admin on this org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can set certain fields to be tracked, and see the changes over time in the History related list for the object.  Take a look:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=5